# How would I make a datetime into a specific custom format?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

Say the current date is 1st Mar 2010, I want to display it like this...

20100301 so like first 4 digits = year, 2 digits = Month, 2 digits = day

is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use format

```
yourdatetimeObj.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Comment: All the answers seemed to be the same now after further editing. Since you got it right the first time, I give you +1. :)

Answer (score 6):

Something like

```
dateTimeObject.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

See [**String Format for DateTime**](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/)

Comment: yeah I was gonna say... why upvote the only one of the 3 answers that was wrong :)

Comment: @Luke: because it was so obviously just a minor typo, your correct answer was not yet around, and the only remaining answer would not even compile as it was given first?

Comment: and @Fredrik - while i agree, we pretty much answered at the same time, and after my answer no one had upvotes still. I suppose some people would have loaded the page in the time between this answer and mine, so I concede :)

Answer (score 2):

```
var mydate = DateTime.Now; // Whatever you want.
mydate.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

Look at [DateTimeFormatInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo(VS.71).aspx) for the other custom format strings you can use.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use the ToString() implementation of the DateTime class, like the examples already given, or use a format string to display it along with other information, like so:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var msg = String.Format("Now: {0:dd/MM/yyyy}", now);
```

Or

```
Console.Write("Now: {0:MM/dd/yyyy}", now);
```